# icacls Command - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: icacls

I am trying to grant *calltake1* access to all existing files within this *CallRecorder\calls* directory

I have tried using this script:

> C:>icacls "C:\Users\calltake1\Documents\CallRecorder\calls" /grant
>   calltake1:(OI)(CI)/F /T

and I keep getting this error message

> Invalid parameter "calltake1:(OI)(CI)/F"